# Homogeneous coordinates and frame change

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I have a transformation $T$ described in a frame $A$ by an homogeneous matrix (of size $4\times4$).
I would like to express $T$ in another frame $B$. How can I do that?
Thank you.

Comment: $STS^{-1}$ where $S$ is the change of basis

Comment: Do you have a link to a demonstration ? I don't get why it's not just only ST

Comment: Because you have to: **1)** transform coordinates wrt $B$ to coordinates wrt $A$ with $S^{-1}$, **2)** apply the transformation $T$, **3)** transform coordinates wrt $A$ to coordinates wrt $B$ with $S$